# How to change position and size of pylab-created image

Tags: python, matplotlib, window

When I use pylab and python under Linux to draw and show an image, like in the following example:

```
img = pylab.imread(filename)
pylab.imshow(img)
pylab.show()
pylab.draw()
```

When I do so, a new window pops up with the image.

My question: How can I influence the position and the size?

Comment: Your subect implies rotatating an image, but your text implies the position of a window...?

Comment: Title fixed. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I still don't understand the question here. Do you want to pick a size and location of the window, and have it scale the image appropriately to that size? If so, I really think `pylab` isn't the right environment for you; you want to use an actual GUI framework.

Comment: Any suggestion for a simple GUI framework working with python?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `pylab`'s Image stuff is that you get a `np.array` of pixel data.

So, you can just do this:

```
img = pylab.imread(filename)
img = img * myTransformationMatrix
pylab.imshow(img)
```

If that immediately tells you what you need to know, great. If you don't understand what matrix multiplication has to do with rotating, translating, and scaling images, `pylab` is probably not the image library you want to use. Just use PIL.

If you're trying to manipulate the windows, rather than the images, `pylab` is *really* not meant for that.

You probably want to use `TkInter`, the windowing library that comes built-in with Python. It's can be ugly, clunky, and slow, and some advanced uses are either impossible or require you to write Tcl code instead of Python… but for simple stuff, it's not going to be a step down from `pylab`. In fact, it's what `pylab` uses under the covers.

If you start to hit the limits of `TkInter`, it's time to look at an external windowing library. You can go with a full GUI framework like Gtk+, Qt, or wx. The Python bindings to the three aren't that different; the important difference is that in the slightly different models of how GUIs work, so read about them and pick the model you like best. Alternatively, you can use something like `pygame`, which does very bare-bones windowing (the kind of thing games would need, rather than, say, word processors).

Comment: As you might have noticed, the title of this question was incorrect. But I was about to find out how to rotate an image as well, so your answer is most appreciated! As I only want to rotate around 90 degrees in a 2-dimensional plane, I probably don't need Euler angles for the rotation matrix...

Comment: @Alex: If you're trying to change the position and size of the image itself, it's still matrix math. If you're trying to change the position of the _window_ on your desktop, that's a completely different thing, and it's not really what `pylab` is intended for.

Comment: Yes, I am afraid it's the window I would like to influence. Hence the mentioning of Linux as OS.